# Symfony2 project - a cache is allways there?

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I have a symfony2 project and the live website is synchronized with a lot of delays with the real database. Event if trying to put a var_dump with an exit in the app.php file in the web directory, the the code is not triggered.

Any idea where can be the cache?

Comment: did you try to `app/console cache:clear`

Comment: @Rufinus, sure, I even deleted it manually.

Comment: with `--env=prod`? i fall in this hole my self a couple of times sometimes there is a cache and nothing seems to clear it.. but normally this only happens when updating.

Comment: Yes, sure. I mean, when we delete the cache manually, no more files are there. But still the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

`app/console cache:clear` only clears the caches registered as CacheClearer/CacheWarmer.

Therefore, it may be that there are still additional caches. Try for example restarting services like Memcached or your Webserver (or PHP-FPM, if you're using that), so APC gets refreshed.

If you're using Nginx, you might have set it up as reverse proxy. Check if there's something like http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/ in your Nginx config.

Another possible reason is client-side caching. Try reloading the page with a forced refresh (Ctrl+Shift+R in Firefox). Or, there's a reverse proxy somewhere between you and your server. Sometimes, IPS install transparent reverse proxies to save bandwidth.